# How does a coredump retrieve values of function arguments at the entry of the function and its actual value during crash?

Tags: c, linux, crash, coredump

I have a coredump, where in each frame, it gives me the values of function arguments at entry level and its actual value during the crash..(It gives me actual value, only if it is changed from entry value)

As I know, coredump is the copy of RAM during the crash. So, at any point of time only the actual value of the variable can be retrieved...

Just want to know how does coredump retrieve entry value of the function argument and also the actual value of the function argument?

Comment: PC and SP is all you need....

Comment: Typically (on a PC-like system) all arguments and local variables are stored in the stack of the process. The stack is part of the memory copied into the dump.